# Time in seconds is same even if you choose any TimeZone?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, epoch

I am using below function to get time in seconds after I apply TimeZone "Europe/Warsaw".

I am getting date correctly, but as soon as I convert date in seconds, my output goes wrong. Server expects seconds in TimeZone "Europe/Warsaw". What's the best possible way to get out of this?

```
public static long getTimeInSeconds() {
    try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        //Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Warsaw"));

        //Will get in Warsaw time zone
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

        Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);

        //Convert time in seconds as required by server.
        return (date1.getTime() / 1000);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Server expects seconds in Warsaw timezone" --> Seconds since when?

Comment: Epoch time is always UTC

Comment: Its in general , since 1970 , as it generally is.

Comment: `getTime()` gets you the number of (milli)seconds passed since 1.1.1970 0:00 *UTC*. Epoch time doesn't know timezones (thankfully, as you'd end up with dozens of different Epochs).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using `java.time` libraries, where timezones are generally more manageable?

Comment: @AnkitOstwal If you want the number of seconds since the epoch, you should do everything in UTC. in other words your method should simply be `return new Date().getTime() / 1000`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `return Instant.now().getEpochSecond();`

Comment: See [*Epoch reference date*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Zinki Actually, [there *are* dozens of epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) reference dates.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [@assylias’ comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133429/time-in-seconds-is-same-even-if-you-choose-any-timezone#comment85273296_49133429).

Answer (score 5):

*"seconds in TimeZone"* doesn't make sense, because **epoch seconds** means *"the number of seconds since epoch"* (where **epoch** is **Jan 1st 1970 at midnight in UTC**), regardless of the timezone.

This value is the same everywhere in the world. But the same epoch seconds value can be converted to a local date and time, depending on the timezone.

Example: right now, the epoch second value is 1520352472. This same value (1520352472 seconds since epoch), is the same everywhere in the world. But this value can represent a different date and time in each timezone:

- March 6th 2018, 16:07:52 in UTC
- March 6th 2018, 13:07:52 in São Paulo (Brazil)
- March **7th** 2018, 01:07:52 in Tokyo

The thing is: no matter in what timezone I'm in, the epoch seconds value will be the same, so you don't need to consider any timezone at all.

The `java.util.Date` class [doesn't have any notion of timezone](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) as well, it just wraps a `long` value representing the number of milliseconds since epoch. So, if you hava a `Date` object, just use this value and divide by 1000:

```
long epochSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

Actually, if you want **just** the numeric value for the current date/time, you don't even need to create a `Date` to get it:

```
long epochSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

To get a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z:

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
```

Alternate route, with same result:

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Warsaw" ) ).toInstant().getEpochSecond()
```

## *java.time*

> What's the best possible way to get out of this?

The best way is to use the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

Apparently you want two things:

- The current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)).
- A count of whole seconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The first, getting current moment in a time zone. We use the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Warsaw" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Aa1FnD).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-02-09T21:14:56.417009+01:00[Europe/Warsaw]

To get the count of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z, extract an `Instant`. This class represents a moment as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Aa1FnD).

> instant.toString(): 2020-02-09T20:14:56.417009Z

Both variables `zdt` and `instant` represent the very same moment, the same point on the timeline. Only the wall-clock time is different.

Interrogate for the count of whole seconds from the epoch reference.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;  // Beware of data-loss, as fractional second is ignored.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Aa1FnD).

> secondsSinceEpoch: 1581279296

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the time-zone after getting the time from the calendar

```
public static long getTimeInSeconds() {

    try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        //Will get in Warsaw time zone
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

        //Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Warsaw"));

        Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);

        //Convert time in seconds as required by server.
        return (date1.getTime() / 1000);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```